# Portrait video in Android VideoView will not take up whole width of the screen

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

I have a VideoView in my layout and in this VideoView I'm attempting to play a vertically-oriented video. I was under the impression that this being a portrait video intended to be displayed in a portrait orientation, things couldn't be easier. Boy, was I wrong.

This is my Java code:

```
videoView1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);


        videoView1.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.video);
        videoView1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView1.start();
            }
        });
videoView1.start();
```

And this is my .xml for the videoview element (which is inside a RelativeLayout, btw):

```
 <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />
```

The most surprising thing I have encountered on what I honestly expected to be a walk in the park is the fact that whatever I do, the video will indeed stretch to fill the height of the screen (so layout_alignParentTop and layout_alignParentBottom are obviously working) **but the damn thing just won't fill the width of the screen!** (yep, I'm frustrated) so there's this already vertical video stretched to a ribbon-like construct down the middle of the screen.

I added the marginLeft and marginRight attributes in a desperate attempt to see if it would work but nothing! Flabbergasted, I removed the centerInParent attribute but again, nothing. I even created a custom VideoView, overrode onMeasure and still nothing.

I tried to programatically set the LayoutParams of the VideoView. Guess what, didn't work.

Comment: What are the RelativeLayout's width and height parametres (parental of `videoView1`)?

Comment: They are both set to match_parent.

Comment: Try adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in manifest

Answer (score 1):

I've created this simple VideoView subclass that displays in full screen while keeping the aspect ration, you can find the **[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/JoaquimLey/3fda0c4492081a24d5610e6ab13569cc)** for the most up to date version, but here's an example:

```
/**
 * Subclass of VideoView to enable video scaling
 * CustomAttribute: "scaleType": "normal", "centerCrop", "fill"
 * <p>
 * Add this stylable:
 * <declare-styleable name="IntroVideoView">
 * <attr name="scaleType" format="integer">
 * <flag name="normal" value="0" />
 * <flag name="centerCrop" value="1" />
 * <flag name="fill" value="2" />
 * </attr>
 * </declare-styleable>
 * <p>
 * Created by joaquimley on 13/01/2017.
 */

public class IntroVideoView extends VideoView {

    private static final int SCALE_TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
    private static final int SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_CROP = 1;
    private static final int SCALE_TYPE_FILL = 2;

    private int mScaleType;
    private int mHorizontalAspectRatioThreshold;
    private int mVerticalAspectRatioThreshold;

    public IntroVideoView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public IntroVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public IntroVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        TypedArray attributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IntroVideoView, 0, 0);
        mScaleType = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.IntroVideoView_scaleType, SCALE_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mScaleType == SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_CROP) {
            applyCenterCropMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else if (mScaleType == SCALE_TYPE_FILL) {
            applyFillMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } // else default/no-op
    }

    @Override
    public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (mScaleType == SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_CROP) {
            applyCenterCropLayout(l, t, r, b);
        } else {
            super.layout(l, t, r, b);
        }
    }

    private void applyCenterCropLayout(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.layout(left + mHorizontalAspectRatioThreshold, top + mVerticalAspectRatioThreshold, right
                + mHorizontalAspectRatioThreshold, bottom + mVerticalAspectRatioThreshold);
    }

    private void applyCenterCropMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int videoWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int videoHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        int viewWidth = getDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec);
        int viewHeight = getDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec);

        mHorizontalAspectRatioThreshold = 0;
        mVerticalAspectRatioThreshold = 0;
        if (videoWidth == viewWidth) {
            int newWidth = (int) ((float) videoWidth / videoHeight * viewHeight);
            setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, viewHeight);
            mHorizontalAspectRatioThreshold = -(newWidth - viewWidth) / 2;
        } else {
            int newHeight = (int) ((float) videoHeight / videoWidth * viewWidth);
            setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth, newHeight);
            mVerticalAspectRatioThreshold = -(newHeight - viewHeight) / 2;

        }
    }

    private void applyFillMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = getDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

And the stylable for the custom attributes:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="IntroVideoView">
        <attr name="scaleType" format="integer">
            <flag name="normal" value="0" />
            <flag name="centerCrop" value="1" />
            <flag name="fill" value="2" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please also specify how to refer this in layout?

Comment: What do you mean? You just need to add this (like any other) custom view to your layout file.

Comment: Sure. The actual culprit was *not using `onConfigurationChanged`*.

Comment: Ok, don't forget to rep if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm an idiot. I'm pretty sure that this is not a mistake even rookie video editors could make (I am not even a rookie) but after rotating the video, due to the aspect ratio, there were black bars added to the side of the portrait video and that's why the video wouldn't fill the screen's width - because the black bars were there! Turns out that after cropping the black bars, the video stretches perfectly - just like before, but with the black bars gone!